# Convert value to javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

I am passing a value into a javascript function from an html button. The value looks like the following.

[image]

As you can see it is an array of key value pairs. How do I convert it so that it looks like the following:

[image]

I want to do this so I can access the array in javascript. Here is the HTML and JS code:

```
<button value="{{data}}" id="generate-btn" name="generate-btn">Generate</button>
```

```
document.getElementById("generate-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("generate button clicked");
  let message = document.getElementById("generate-btn").value;
});
```

Comment: So, it is already in an array. What you showed you wanted it to be in, is also in an array.  They have keys and values but that is just the object itself which is in the array. I'll need more of your code to help out. As it appears the code you have put in is just trying to get the text value of a button and save it to a message variable which is just the whole array itself.

Comment: So you want to parse an array out of a string? Use [`JSON5.parse()`](https://json5.org). For alternatives, see *[Is there a canonical question on how to parse "invalid" JSON?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426901)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the JSON like:

```
document.getElementById("generate-btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let message = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
  console.dir(message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this, but I get an error ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 2 (line 1 column 3)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>```